# How to use mpirun to use different CPU cores for different programs?

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

I have a virtual machine with 32 cores.
I am running some simulations for which I need to utilize 16 cores at one time.

I use the below command to run a job on 16 cores :

> mpirun -n 16 *program_name* *args* > log.out 2>&1

This program runs on 16 cores.

Now if I want to run the same programs on the rest of the cores, with different arguments, I use the same command like

> mpirun -n 8 *program_name* *diff_args* > log_1.out 2>&1

The second process utilizes the same 16 cores that were utilized earlier. 
How can use mpirun to run this process on 8 different cores, not the previous 16 that first job was using.

I am using headless Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Are you sure you have 32 *real* cores and not just 16 + hyperthreading?  Otherwise, the scheduler of your operating system should take care of that.

Comment: which version of Open MPI are you using ?
recent versions bind to a NUMA domain (e.g. socket, most of the time), so that looks a bit odd. what if you `mpirun -np 16 grep Cpus_allowed_list /proc/self/status` ?

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes I have 32 real cores and not 16 + hyperthreading.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet The package version is `1.10.2`. Also I ran the above command for both 16 and 32 values, the `Cpus_allowed_list:` is given all distinct values where as if I run for values above 32, it assigns the value as `0-31`.

Comment: `1.10.2` is now outdated. a simple option is to `mpirun -bind-to none ...` in order to disable binding (and let the OS decide)

Answer (score 5):

Open MPI's launcher supports restricting the CPU set via the `--cpu-set` option. It accepts a set of logical CPUs expressed as a list of the form `s0,s1,s2,...`, where each list entry is either a single logical CPU number of a range of CPUs `n-m`.

Provided that the logical CPUs in your VM are numbered consecutively, what you have to do is:

```bash
mpirun --cpu-set  0-15 --bind-to core -n 16 program_name args > log.out 2>&1
mpirun --cpu-set 16-23 --bind-to core -n  8 program_name diff_args > log_1.out 2>&1
```

`--bind-to core` tells Open MPI to bind the processes to separate cores each while respecting the CPU set provided in the `--cpu-set` argument.

It might be helpful to use a tool such as `lstopo` (part of the `hwloc` library of Open MPI) to obtain the topology of the system, which helps in choosing the right CPU numbers and, e.g., prevents binding to hyperthreads, although this is less meaningful in a virtualised environment.

(Note that `lstopo` uses a confusing naming convention and calls the OS logical CPUs *physical*, so look for the numbers in the `(P#n)` entries. `lstopo -p` hides the `hwloc` logical numbers and prevents confusion.)