# Weird behaviour of mpirun, always strictly binding to cores 0 and 1 when starting 2 processes

Tags: mpi, openmpi

Some weird behaviour was recently observed by a colleague, and I have been able to reproduce it. We have a computer for simulations, which is powered by two Xeon processors with 18 cores each, giving us 36 cores to work with.

When, we launch an application using 2 processes, mpi always binds on cores 0 and 1 of socket 0. Thus, if we run 4 simulations using 2 processes each, cores 0 and 1 are doing all the work with a CPU-usage of each process of 25%.

See the reported bindings of MPI below. When we use more than 2 processes for each simulation, MPI behaves as expected, i.e. when running 4 simulations using 3 processes each, then 12 cores are working with each process having 100% CPU-use.

```
[user@apollo3 tmp]$ mpirun -np 2 --report-bindings myApp -parallel > run01.log &
[1] 5374
[user@apollo3 tmp]$ [apollo3:05374] MCW rank 0 bound to socket 0[core 0[hwt 0]]: [B/././././././././././././././././.][./././././././././././././././././.]
[apollo3:05374] MCW rank 1 bound to socket 0[core 1[hwt 0]]: [./B/./././././././././././././././.][./././././././././././././././././.]

[user@apollo3 tmp]$ mpirun -np 2 --report-bindings myApp > run02.log &
[2] 5385
[user@apollo3 tmp]$ [apollo3:05385] MCW rank 0 bound to socket 0[core 0[hwt 0]]: [B/././././././././././././././././.][./././././././././././././././././.]
[apollo3:05385] MCW rank 1 bound to socket 0[core 1[hwt 0]]: [./B/./././././././././././././././.][./././././././././././././././././.]
```

What could be the reason for this binding behavior of MPI?

We run OpenMPI 1.10 on our machine

```
[user@apollo3 tmp]$ mpirun --version
mpirun (Open MPI) 1.10.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long story short, this is not a bug but a feature.

various instances of　`mpirun` do not communicate with each other, and hence each MPI job believes it is running alone on the system, and so uses cores 0 and 1.

the simplest option is to disable binding if you know you will be running several jobs on the same machine.

```
mpirun -bind-to none ...
```

will do the trick.

A better option is to use a resource manager (such as SLURM, PBS or others) and make sure Open MPI was built to support it.
The resource managers will allocate different set of cores to each job, and hence there will be no more overlap.

A similar question was asked recently, see yet an other option at [How to use mpirun to use different CPU cores for different programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47784610/how-to-use-mpirun-to-use-different-cpu-cores-for-different-programs)

Comment: The weird thing is, that my problem does not occur, when using 3 or more processes. It's only when I use 2, that mpi binds to the first two cores. In all other cases, mpi binds to free, unoccupied cores.

Comment: On a side note, using `--bind-to none` did avoid the problem I described in my question. However, I do not yet grasp the why.

Comment: The default policy is to bind 2 MPI tasks jobs to core, and bind to socket otherwise. If you use 3 MPI tasks jobs, then socket 0 will end up with more tasks than socket 1.

Comment: @DohnJoe, just tell everyone using the system at the same time to put `export OMPI_MCA_hwloc_base_binding_policy=none` (or `setenv OMPI_MCA_hwloc_base_binding_policy none` for [t]csh) in their shell startup file (`.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, `.whateverrc`). This is equivalent to specifying `--bind-to none`, but achieved via MCA parameters in the environment. We had to implement this for all users of our cluster once Open MPI introduced the automatic binding.

Comment: @HristoIliev aren't you using a resource manager ? if you are using a (correctly configured) resource manager and Open MPI was properly built to support it, you should not have any issues when running flat MPI. imho disabling binding is only a lesser evil when running hybrid MPI+OpenMP, and i would not recommend it by default.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, we are using LSF without the binding options. LSF does not provide core mapping, just the number of slots on each host. We disabled the automatic binding exactly because it was causing problems with hybrid applications.